# Adding to a value in a loop counter in Python

Tags: python, variables, counter, pyautogui

I’m trying to get it add 1 to streak every time the loop runs, but it keeps the same number. I’m trying to make a counter every time it sees red.

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

streak = 0
r = 1
def color():

    pix = pyautogui.pixel(500, 285)
    red = pix[0]
    print (red)

    if red == 222:

        x = streak + r
        print (x)

while True:
    color()
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: `streak = streak + 1` is the correct way to add 1 to streak.  Your code sets `streak = 0` and `r = 1` and those values are never changed, so of course the result of `streak + r` is always the same.

Comment: `streak` starts at 0, and is never changed.  `r` starts at 1, and is never changed.  `streak + r` can therefore never produce any value other than 1.  You need to actually change one of those variables, and since it necessarily exists outside of the function where it's being changed, you will need a `global` declaration to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code allows you to know how many times you have seen red.

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

r = 0


def color():
    global r
    pix = pyautogui.pixel(950, 540)
    color_var = pix[0]
    print(color_var)

    if color_var > 222:
        r += 1
        if r > 1:
            print(f"I have seen red {r} times")
        else:
            print(f"I have seen red {r} time")


while True:
    color()
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is easy you need add 1 to streak inside the if, instead you are creating a new var and adding the value in it you never change the streak init value

this line `x = streak + r` should be like this `streak  = streak + r`

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way is to use :

```
number += othernumber
```

example :

```
number += 1
```